# How to access a qualification I created in Amazon mechanical turk?

Tags: boto3, mechanicalturk

Using boto3 to access the rest API I can retrieve my QualificationTypeId,just like I can retrieve my HIT_Type_Id when I create a HIT.  With the HIT I can then construct a URL like:

```
https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=35E1491KDIVXSN2TCLNVR3G3U5I78V
```

where that random string is

```
hit_type_id = response['HIT']['HITTypeId']
```

How do I construct a URL for the qualification given the string extracted as:

```
qualification_type_id = response['QualificationType']['QualificationTypeId']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
https://www.mturk.com/mturk/requestqualification?qualificationId=[qualification type ID]
```

So it'll look like this:

```
https://www.mturk.com/mturk/requestqualification?qualificationId=32O4TCGYF66STTNO0IKIA3U7WHZ1D4
```

Be aware that www.mturk.com is the current Worker site, but that they're working on a new Worker site at worker.mturk.com. That new site doesn't yet have support for Qualifications (Workers can request them at www.mturk.com). But it does mean that there's a chance this URL changes at some point in the future.

Hope that helps!

Comment: excellent! and this works in sandbox also with workersandbox.mturk.com instead of www.mturk.com

Comment: great. happy to help!